# mysql multiple joins with conditions on multiple table query performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance

suppose tables:

main (1M rows):
 id, a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, amounts, year, main_col

a(500 rows):
 id, a_col1, a_col2

b(2000 rows):
 id, b_col1, b_col2, b_col3

c(500 rows):
 id, c_col1, c_col2

d(1000 rows):
 id, d_col1, d_col2

And we have query like:

```
select sum(amounts), main_col 
   join a on a.id = main.a_id 
   join b on b.id = main.b_id 
   join c on c.id = main.c_id 
   join d on d.id = main.d_id 
   where a.a_col1 in (...) 
     and a.a_col2 in (..) 
     and b.b_col1 in (...) 
     and b.b_col2 in (...) 
     and b.b_col3 in (..) 
     and c.c_col1 in (..) 
     and c.c_col2 in (..) 
     and d.d_col1 in (..) 
     and d.d_col2 in (..)
     and year = 2011

   group by main.main_col
```

any idea who to create index on the main table to improve the query performance ?

thanks

Update:
indexes are added to a,b,c,d tables for the columns show up in where
i've tried multiple column indexes on main table (a_id, b_id, c_id, d_id, main_col) which have the best performance than others like add individual indexes on the a_id, b_id... , but  it still not fast enough for requirement, on query will take 7 seconds to run for the maximum situation

Comment: If you're really struggling to optimise the query and you've tried everything, you might want to look at your schema. It may be possible to denormalise/create aggregate tables etc to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE INDEX id_main ON main(id)

You could create multiple indexes on additional columns and see how that works for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: primary key(id) index is added by default, i've tried to add multiple indexes for the foreign keys on main table, and use explain to check the sql and mysql is not picking the indexes for the query

Comment: Okay.  You didn't state that you had primary keys on your tables and I didn't want to assume you did, rather just how to apply an index.  The MySQL engine will pick an index/execution path to follow based on what it thinks is best.  You could read this article on how to performance tune your queries:  http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on specifics like how selective each join is, how big each table is, etc.  In general it might be wise to add one or more indices on the foreign keys of your main table, but who could say from that limited info?

It might also help to get an idea of how your query is executing-- try looking at MySQL's "explain" or "explain extended".

Answer (score 0):

Since the primary keys are already indexed by default, the join cannot be optimized by adding more indexes. So that leaves your where statements. So it could help adding indexes to the x.x_colN columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have an index on your group_by I think